# What kind of discrete convolution is this?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, convolution

Let `x[n]` and `y[n]` be defined for `n=0,1, ..., N-1`.

This (for example with Python's scipy fft / ifft)

```
a = ifft (fft(x) * fft(y))
```

should give the convolution

$$a[k] = (x * y)[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] y[k-n]$$

But is it done with

- `y[i] = 0` if $i<0$  ?

or

- `y[i] = y[N+i]` if $i<0$ ?  (ex : `y[-3] = y[N-3]` )     (in this case do we call it **circular convolution**?)

Note : More generally, I have good books about signal processing / Fourier transform in general, but they are not really handy handbooks for discrete finite signals (`x[n]` for  `n=0,1, ..., N-1`). Do you have a good reference of handbook for this case (discrete finite signals) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast (FFT/IFFT) convolution results in circular convolution.

(But if sufficient zero-padding is explicitly added before the initial FFTs, circular and linear convolution would then produce identical results.)

Comment: thanks. Is there an amount of zero-padding for which we are sure the results are identical ?

Comment: The length of both signals after zero padding has to be `length(x) + length(y) - 1`

Comment: Has to be at least that length, however one can zero pad to a greater length for a faster FFT (better factorable length).

Comment: @hotpaw2: and in python that faster length is the nearest 5-smooth number: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2146 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19649737/125507